# Roll, Pitch and Yaw of Orbital Planes

Tags: orbital-elements, celestial-mechanics

I have been reading about celestial mechanics and particularly about planetary orbits. I understand that a planet's orbit can be tilted (pitched) with respect to the Earth's ecliptic and that it might precess (yaw) over time. But I have not come across any indication that another planet's orbital plane might be rolled with respect to the Earth's.

I have also found references to Keplerian orbital elements, but I don't see that any of them indicate roll. Am I misunderstanding the situation? If not, would someone point me at an elementary resource where I can learn about this?

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding, but doesn't the planet's rotation constitute "roll"?

Comment: @barrycarter - A planet's rotation is a rotation about the instantaneous z axis. That's yaw, not roll. Roll is about the x axis.

Comment: OK, but the x axis is always the direction of travel, correct? So wouldn't rotation contribute to both roll and yaw?

Comment: I am unconcerned with rotation, only revolution.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong terms. Engineers use yaw, pitch, and roll to describe the orientation of a vehicle. Some erroneously call these rotations Euler angles. Astronomers and physicists use true Euler angles, a rotation about the Z axis of some reference plane, followed by a second rotation about the once-rotated X axis, followed by a third rotation about the twice-rotated Z axis. Note that the Tait-Bryan angles (aka Cardano angles) use a sequence of rotations about three distinct axes. Euler angles use only two axes.

The first rotation is the planet's [axial precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_precession) angle. The second rotation is the planet's [axial tilt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt), or obliquity. The third rotation represents the planet's daily rotation. The rates at which the precession and obliquity change are much smaller than the quickly-changing third angle.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand, so I will rephrase. I have a reference plane (e.g. the ecliptic) with a preferred direction (corresponding to the Earth's major axis. I now have another plane, for example, that of Mars's orbit. I understand that this is inclined ("pitched") with respect to the ecliptic by about 1.85 degrees. Mars's major axis, as projected onto the ecliptic, intersects at angle ("yaw"). I am interested in rotation around the third axis, which with planes or ships is called "roll". I would appreciate a pointer to an elementary document on this topic.

Comment: @SpencerRugaber - Forget the third axis. Forget yaw, pitch, and roll. That  is not how astronomers describe the orientation of a planet. They instead use proper Euler angles. Read what I wrote. Use google to search for the terms I used. I'll add links to wikipedia articles to my answer as a starting point in your understanding.